# drop down list data bind function refreshing list, but also adding already existing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, html-select

I have form which inserts values into a DropDownList. When I say

```
   DropDownList.DataBind() ;
```

in the save function - it appends the new field i just typed as well as all the other already existing options on the  DropDownList. any advice on how to stop this? the  DropDownList is being populated by a separate data source.

```
protected void BtnNewTugSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //saving stuff
            con.Close();

            DropDownListX.DataBind();


        }

    catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }

    }


    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceT"
                                            DataTextField="T_Name" DataValueField="T_ID" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ShowNewRateBtn">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="&lt;Select&gt;" Enabled="True" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:Button ID="NewTug" runat="server" Text="New Tug" OnClick="NewTug_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceT" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings X %>"
                                            SelectCommand="SELECT [A, [B] FROM [C]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Please post your code. Both the server side and the client side. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before retrieve your data you should write

```
try
{
    DropDownList.Items.Clear();
    //saving stuff
    DropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

Using the DropDownList.Items.Clear(); the items of your dropdownlist will be deleted before you will get your new data and you feed the dropdownlist.